# getting readable text from unicode

Tags: php, string

```
print_r(json_decode('{"t":"\u05D0\u05E0\u05D2\u05DC\u05D9\u05EA"}'));
```

this is working and gives output in hebrew but when I put a name of string instead hard coded

```
(print_r(json_decode($str));
```

where

```
$str = "\u05ea\u05b5\u05bc\u05dc\u05be\u05d0\u05b8\u05d1";)
```

then it gives empty output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `\u05ea\u05b5\u05bc\u05dc\u05be\u05d0\u05b8\u05d1` is not a JSON string, whereas `{"t":"\u05D0\u05E0\u05D2\u05DC\u05D9\u05EA"}` is. So `json_decode` will return `NULL` as a result.

Please read about [JSON](http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php) and particularly the functions [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php) and [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

Comment: $orignalStr = "\u05ea\u05b5\u05bc\u05dc\u05be\u05d0\u05b8\u05d1";           $str = "'{".'"t"'.":".$orignalStr.'"'."}'";   now the string is same but m having empty output

Comment: No it isn't, you have issues with concatenation and simple/double quotes. [Check here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/665b37013c7678ca73e532efa5fd7a364535d477).

Comment: No probs mate. Still, if you already have a unicode string (such as `$str` in your post), IMO it's redundant and unefficient to prepend and append stuff to it to build a JSON string, only to decode it later.

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = '{"t":"\u05D0\u05E0\u05D2\u05DC\u05D9\u05EA"}';
```

your $str variable has wrong syntax of json array.. put above string in $str

Comment: $orignalStr = "\u05ea\u05b5\u05bc\u05dc\u05be\u05d0\u05b8\u05d1";           $str = "'{".'"t"'.":".$orignalStr.'"'."}'";   now the string is same but m having empty output

Comment: No. This --  $str = "'{".'"t"'.":".$orignalStr.'"'."}'";  is not same as $str = '{"t":"\u05D0\u05E0\u05D2\u05DC\u05D9\u05EA"}';... any7 way if u still want to concatenate then u must escape double quotes.. like this..(\")

Answer (score 0):

The strings are not the same. In the first code example your string is a JSON object with a string containing unicode characters. In the second example it is just a unicode string, which, I assume, is not valid JSON, so `json_decode` can't handle it.

Comment: $orignalStr = "\u05ea\u05b5\u05bc\u05dc\u05be\u05d0\u05b8\u05d1"; $str = "'{".'"t"'.":".$orignalStr.'"'."}'"; now the string is same but m having empty output

Comment: This platform is **not** a code writing service. You explained your problem, I explained why your problem exists. There was no need to add code to this answer, so why should I?

Comment: I got the answer from the same platform, well thanks for this new information

Comment: The answer you got is equivalent to the one I gave you.

Comment: i got code also in comment section, a link is given .. check please (http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/665b37013c7678ca73e532efa5fd7a364535d477)